# ImportError: cannot import name 'Task' from 'app.models'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, import, flask-sqlalchemy, importerror

Ok so I am new to flask and i am trying to set up a simple task manager. And I have a problem with importing my database.

When I made my first import my db was named ***User*** and it had fields like email, username, ...

Now all I did was renaming the call of database form ***User*** to ***Task*** and changed some fields or added more.

and now when I run a command:

> >>> from app.models import Task

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Task' from 'app.models' (/Users/janzaplatil/Desktop/taskmanager/app/models.py)
```

but if I run a `>>> from app.models import User` all is fine. But it makes no sense to me since there is no class ***User***, only Task

My model python file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db

class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))


  def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task {}>'.format(self.task)
```

My flask app:

```
from app import app, db
from app.models import Task

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'Task': Task}
```

Comment: Remove any `*.pyc` files and try again.

Comment: ok thanks it worked. what does pyc file do ?

Comment: It's compiled python bytecode. Python regenerates those. Every so often, for reasons (like renaming files), you'll end up with a stale .pyc that confuses things.